Celery task not working with WebSocket (Flask)
I'm working on a project that requires both Celery and WebSocket functionality. I'm using the Flask framework along with Flask-SocketIO for the WebSocket implementation. However, I'm having trouble running both Celery and WebSocket together. I'm using Eventlet for the WebSocket, but whenever I run the app with Gunicorn and Eventlet, Celery stops accepting connections after one or two successful attempts. If I remove Eventlet, Celery works perfectly, but the WebSocket fails to connect.
below is my Dockerfile configuration for the api
FROM python:3.8-alpine3.15

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV FLASK_APP=runserver.py

# Install dependencies needed to build psycopg2
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    gcc \
    musl-dev \
    python3-dev \
    postgresql-dev \
    libc-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    build-base \
    tzdata \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 7000
#CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:7000", "-w", "4", "runserver:app"]     # for (celery)
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:7000", "-w", "4", "-k", "eventlet", "runserver:app"] # for websocket


celery dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-alpine3.15

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Install dependencies needed to build psycopg2
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    gcc \
    musl-dev \
    python3-dev \
    postgresql-dev \
    libc-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    build-base \
    tzdata \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app

CMD ["celery", "-A", "celery_config.utils.cel_workers.celery", "worker", "--loglevel=info", "--concurrency=4", "--autoscale=4,2", "-E", "-B"]


and below is the error i get when celery fails
teamflow-api     | Traceback (most recent call last):
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 30, in __call__
teamflow-api     |     return self.__value__
teamflow-api     | AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'
teamflow-api     |
teamflow-api     | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
teamflow-api     |
teamflow-api     | Traceback (most recent call last):
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 446, in _reraise_as_library_errors
teamflow-api     |     yield
teamflow-nginx   | 192.168.65.1 - - [11/Sep/2024:07:32:15 +0000] "POST /api/v1/auth/resend-otp HTTP/1.1" 500 55 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.41.2"
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
teamflow-api     |     return retry_over_time(
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 312, in retry_over_time
teamflow-api     |     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 877, in _connection_factory
teamflow-api     |     self._connection = self._establish_connection()
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 812, in _establish_connection
teamflow-api     |     conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 201, in establish_connection
teamflow-api     |     conn.connect()
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 323, in connect
teamflow-api     |     self.transport.connect()
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 129, in connect
teamflow-api     |     self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 184, in _connect
teamflow-api     |     self.sock.connect(sa)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 265, in connect
teamflow-api     |     socket_checkerr(fd)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 50, in socket_checkerr
teamflow-api     |     raise OSError(err, errno.errorcode[err])
teamflow-api     | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
teamflow-api     |
teamflow-api     | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
teamflow-api     |
teamflow-api     | Traceback (most recent call last):
teamflow-api     |   File "/app/endpoints/authentication.py", line 318, in resend_otp
teamflow-api     |     send_mail.delay(payload)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 425, in delay
teamflow-api     |     return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 575, in apply_async
teamflow-api     |     return app.send_task(
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 788, in send_task
teamflow-api     |     amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 510, in send_task_message
teamflow-api     |     ret = producer.publish(
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 177, in publish
teamflow-api     |     return _publish(
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 523, in _ensured
teamflow-api     |     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 186, in _publish
teamflow-api     |     channel = self.channel
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 209, in _get_channel
teamflow-api     |     channel = self._channel = channel()
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 32, in __call__
teamflow-api     |     value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 225, in <lambda>
teamflow-api     |     channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 895, in default_channel
teamflow-api     |     self._ensure_connection(**conn_opts)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 433, in _ensure_connection
teamflow-api     |     return retry_over_time(
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
teamflow-api     |     self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
teamflow-api     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 450, in _reraise_as_library_errors
teamflow-api     |     raise ConnectionError(str(exc)) from exc
teamflow-api     | kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED
teamflow-api     |  error@auth/resend-otp TRACEBACK
teamflow-api     | [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED error@auth/resend-otp

my docker-compose
services:
  celery:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.celery
    container_name: teamflow-celery
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - teamflow_network
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - celery
    container_name: teamflow-api
    networks:
      - teamflow_network
    env_file:
      - .env
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: teamflow-redis
    command: --port 6380
    expose:
      - 6380
    networks:
      - teamflow_network
    ports:
      - 6380:6380

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: teamflow-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
      - teamflow_network

networks:
  teamflow_network:
    external: true


the celery config
from app_config import create_app
from celery import Celery, shared_task
from flask import render_template_string
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os
from datetime import datetime
import celery_config.schedule_config as celeryConfig
import traceback

app = create_app()


def make_celery(app=app):
    """
    As described in the doc
    """
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=f"redis://{os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST')}:{os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT')}",
        broker=f"redis://{os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST')}:{os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT')}",
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    celery.config_from_object(celeryConfig)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


celery = make_celery()


@shared_task
def send_mail(context):
    try:
        print("Sending Mail")
        smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        smtp_port = 587
        smtp_user = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
        smtp_password = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD')

        server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, smtp_port)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(smtp_user, smtp_password)

        from_email = "support@teamflow.com"
        to_email = context['email']
        subject = context['subject']

        # Construct the path to the HTML file within the templates folder
        template_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'templates', context['template_name'])

        # Read the HTML file content
        with open(template_path, 'r') as html_file:
            body = html_file.read()

        # send context inside the html file
        body = render_template_string(body, **context)

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = from_email
        msg['To'] = to_email
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        # Change the MIME type to 'html'
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

        server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())

        server.quit()
        return "Mail sent successfully"

    except Exception as e:
        print(traceback.format_exc(), "error@celery/send_mail")
        print(e, "error@celery/send_mail")
        return "Failed to send mail"

the extensions.py
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_cors import CORS
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

naming_convention = {
    "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=MetaData(naming_convention=naming_convention))
migrate = Migrate()
jwt = JWTManager()
socketio = SocketIO(cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode='eventlet')

cors = CORS()


the create app function
def create_app(config_name='development'):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_obj[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    socketio.init_app(app)
    jwt.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app, resources={r"/socket.io/*": {"origins": "*"}})

the runserver.py
from app_config import create_app
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from message_socket import socketio
import redis


load_dotenv()


app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=7000)


and the socketIo code
from flask_socketio import emit, join_room
from models import create_message, is_project_valid
from http_status import HttpStatus
from status_res import StatusRes
from extensions import socketio
from flask_jwt_extended import current_user, jwt_required


@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect_handler():
    print('Client connected')


@socketio.on('join-room')
@jwt_required()
def on_join(data):
    project_id = data.get('project_id')
    print(current_user.id, "current_user.id")
    if not is_project_valid(project_id):
        print("Invalid project ID")
        emit('error-message', {
            'status': HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            'status_res': StatusRes.FAILED,
            'message': "Invalid project ID"
        })
        return
    join_room(project_id)


# error handler
@socketio.on_error()
def error_handler(e):
    print(e, "error@socketio.on_error")
    emit('error-message', {
        'status': HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        'status_res': StatusRes.FAILED,
        'message': str(e)
    })


@socketio.on('send-message')
@jwt_required()
def send_message(data):
    project_id = data.get('project_id')
    print(project_id, "project_id")

    if not is_project_valid(project_id):
        print("Invalid project ID")
        emit('error-message', {
            'status': HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            'status_res': StatusRes.FAILED,
            'message': "Invalid project ID"
        })  # Send error to the requesting client only
        return

    try:
        content = data.get('content', None)
        author_id = current_user.id

        if not content:
            emit('error-message', {
                'status': HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                'status_res': StatusRes.FAILED,
                'message': "Content is required"
            })
            return

        # Assuming create_message is a function that saves the message to the database
        msg = create_message(content, author_id, project_id)
        if not msg:
            raise Exception("Network Error")

        emit('receive-message', msg.to_dict(), room=project_id)
    except Exception as e:
        # General error handling
        print(e, "error@message_socket/send-message")
        emit('error', {
            'status': HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            'status_res': StatusRes.FAILED,
            'message': "Network Error"
        }, room=project_id)


